# Material UI v4: extending PaletteColorOptions

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I want to do something very straightforward in Material UI v4's (v4.11) palette: add a new field to `PaletteColorOptions`. Let's say I want to add `darker?: string`

This is the type definition in the relevant Material UI module:

**createPalette.d.ts**

```js
export type PaletteColorOptions = SimplePaletteColorOptions | ColorPartial;

export interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
}
```

There is [a merged PR to Material UI](https://github.com/BennyHinrichs/material-ui/blob/03ba2110f041746e893b70c588a90a32451f22cc/docs/src/pages/customization/palette/palette.md#adding-new-colors) which adds to their documentation an example of how to add a new Palette Color Option via module augmentation. This is what they suggest:

```js
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' {
  interface PaletteColor {
    darker?: string
  }
  interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
    darker?: string
  }
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work - I'm getting the following error when trying to add `darker` to one of the color objects - suggesting that I did not manage to add the new field to PaletteColorOptions

> Type '{ dark: string; main: string; contrastText: string; darker: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PaletteColorOptions | undefined'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'darker' does not exist in type 'PaletteColorOptions'.ts(2322)
> createPalette.d.ts(105, 3): The expected type comes from property 'primary' which is declared here on type 'PaletteOptions'

I also tried to add similar definitions to the `createPalette` module (again via module augmentation as suggested in the example above), but I'm getting the same TypeScript error shown above.

```js
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  interface PaletteColor {
    darker?: string
  }
  interface PaletteColorOptions {
    darker?: string
  }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it in the end. Here is how I did it:

**palette.ts** (a file we had created to define the palette)

```js
interface ExtendedPaletteColorOptions extends SimplePaletteColorOptions {
  darker?: string
}

interface ExtendedPaletteOptions extends PaletteOptions {
  primary: ExtendedPaletteColorOptions
  secondary: ExtendedPaletteColorOptions
  text: Partial<TypeText>
  error: ExtendedPaletteColorOptions
  warning: ExtendedPaletteColorOptions
  info: ExtendedPaletteColorOptions
  success: ExtendedPaletteColorOptions
  // And your custom palette options if you defined them, e.g:
  // brand: ExtendedPaletteColorOptions
}

const palette: ExtendedPaletteOptions = {
  // Our palette, which now supports the new `lighter`, for example:
  primary: {
    main: '#555555',
    dark: '#333333',
    darker: '#111111',
  }
}
```

**theme.d.ts** (a file we had created for module augmentation of the material-ui modules)

```js
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  interface PaletteColor {
    lighter: string
  }
}
```